# Equivalent condition of uniform integrability of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, uniform-integrability

Here's the definition I have for a sequence of random variables to be uniformly integrable:

$(1)$ A sequence of random variables $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ is uniformly integrable (U.I.) if for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $K$ such that for each $n$, $\mathbb{E}[|X_n|I\{|X_n|>K\}]<\epsilon. $

I've seen that U.I. implies the following:

$(2)$ Given $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that if $\mathbb{P}(A)<\delta$, then $\mathbb{E}(|X_n|I_A)<\epsilon $.

In the book I'm reading, the author states a fact about a condition that implies U.I. and in the proof, he just shows that $(2)$ holds. Is it the case that $(1)\iff(2)$?

Also, this is supposed to be pre-measure-theoretic, so if you can answer my question without measure theory that would be ideal. Thanks in advance for your input!

Comment: what answer are you hoping for? the short answer is that 'yes' they are the same.

Comment: I was hoping the answer is 'yes.' The author doesn't mention that the two are equivalent, but uses the fact that they (apparently) are!

Comment: do you want a proof?

Comment: That would be nice!

Comment: Can you just take the event $A=\{|X_n|>K\}$?

Comment: not quite, but you see that is where the functions are the biggest, hence giving you the biggest integral $E(|X_n|1_{A})$

Comment: It's worth noting that these definitions are equivalent on a probability space, but NOT in general (actually they are also equivalent over on $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ under Lebesgue measure). See http://epwalsh.com/math/post001.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~beresty/teach/pmnotes.pdf

see page 42. the author uses (2) as definiton, and prove they are equivalent. The proof is fairly short. about 1/3 of the page

It might also beneficial read about 1/2 of page before it.